# C# execute a background thread every number of seconds (scheduled)

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I just started learning C#, I am a Java programmer. In Java I am able to do the following:

```
    int corePoolSize = 1;
    long initialDelay = 0;//0 seconds
    long delay = 60;//60 seconds
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
    stpe.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new MyDemoClass(), initialDelay, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

which would execute the Runnable "MyDemoClass" in a background thread every 60 seconds.

How would I do this in C#? I have looked at its ThreadPool [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but it seems to be not what I am looking for.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer.aspx or http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morgan/archive/2008/12/18/periodic-execution-in-net.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tcs6ww8.aspx) with an `Interval`, wired to `Elapsed` event handler that performs your required periodic logic.

> The Timer component is a server-based timer, which allows you to
>   specify a recurring interval at which the Elapsed event is raised in
>   your application. You can then handle this event to provide regular
>   processing. For example, suppose you have a critical server that must
>   be kept running 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. You could create a
>   service that uses a Timer to periodically check the server and ensure
>   that the system is up and running. If the system is not responding,
>   the service could attempt to restart the server or notify an
>   administrator.

You should not need thread pool to get this done.

Comment: Thank you Steve. This seems to be what I am looking for, I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you do wind up using threads yourself, try to use `Task Parallel Library` rather than bespoke constructs using `System.Threading` primitives - this mirrors advice to prefer `java.util.concurrent`, to some degree.

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for System.Threading.Timer
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx

> "Use a TimerCallback delegate to specify the method you want the Timer to execute. The timer delegate is specified when the timer is constructed, and cannot be changed. The method does not execute on the thread that created the timer; it executes on a ThreadPool thread supplied by the system."